# Is there any difference between these 2 glob patterns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

```
images/**/*.{png,svg}
images/**/*.+(png|svg)
```

When I test them they usually produce the same result. But just need to make sure they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are *not* exactly the same and they will both potentially yield different results - refer to the [glob primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) for further info. It states:

> `+(pattern|pattern|pattern)` Matches one or more occurrences of the patterns provided.

Your second pattern; `images/**/*.+(png|svg)`, will match ***one or more occurrences*** of either `png` or `svg` at the end of a filename.

However, your first pattern; `images/**/*.{png,svg}`, will match only when there is ***one occurrence*** of either `png` or `svg` at the end of a filename.

**Example:**

Let's say we have four files named:

- `foo.svg`
- `foo.svgsvg`
- `foo.png`
- `foo.pngpngpng`

and their paths are:

```
.
├── images
│   ├── ...
│   └── quux
│       ├── foo.svg
│       ├── foo.svgsvg
│       ├── foo.png
│       └── foo.pngpngpng
```

**Matched Results**

Given your two example patterns - your first pattern; `images/**/*.{png,svg}`, will match the following two paths only:

- `images/quux/foo.svg`
- `images/quux/foo.png`

*Note: the paths to files `foo.svgsvg` and `foo.pngpngpng` have been ignored*

However your second pattern; `images/**/*.+(png|svg)` will match all four file paths, namely:

- `images/quux/foo.svg`
- `images/quux/foo.svgsvg`
- `images/quux/foo.png`
- `images/quux/foo.pngpngpng`

---

> "When I test them they usually produce the same result."

This is because it's unlikely that you've ever had a file with an extension such as `.pngpng` or `.svgsvgsvg` (i.e. when it has more than one occurrence of `png` or `svg` at the end). Nor is it likely that you ever will.

However, I recommend that you utilize the first glob pattern, i.e. `images/**/*.{png,svg}`, as it's more concise to what you're actually wanting to match.